# JQuery find and delete elements between other element

Tags: jquery

I need to find and delete all `<br>` elements that stays between images.
Example:

```
<img src="something.jpg">
<br>
<img src="nonono.jpg">
<br>
<img src="xyz.jpg">
<br>
<img src="ispumlorem.jpg">
```

How can I achieve this usging JQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For the first part of the condition, that the `br` tag is preceded by an `img`, `img + br` will suffice
2. For the second part of the condition, that the `br` tag is also proceeded by an `img`, navigate to the `img` using `next()`, than navigate back using `prev()`.

This will insure that you only get those `br` tags that are preceeded **and** proceeded by `img` tags

```js
$('img + br').next('img').prev('br').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="something.jpg">
<br>
<img src="nonono.jpg">
<br>
<img src="xyz.jpg">
<br>
<img src="ispumlorem.jpg">
<br>
<div></div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need: only the 'br' elements between images. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

jQuery uses CSS rules to select elements, so you can use this:

```
$('br').remove();
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nj03rp76/)